# GAE task, are the urls secure by design?

Tags: google-app-engine, task

I'm trying to wrap my head around Google App Engine and more specifically at the Tasks.

My question is about security, if I define a queue like :

```
- url: /queues/long-task
  script: urlhandlers.QueueLongTask.app
  login: admin
```

Will I be sure that the /queues/long-task can only be accessed by admin AND task system ? I was not able to find a reference about this in the Google documentation.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, login: admin takes care of it.

Here you can find more info on the documentation:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview-push#Python_Securing_URLs_for_tasks

You can also use the headers like `X-AppEngine-QueueName` if you want to do specific things only when this is called from a task:

"These headers are set internally by Google App Engine. If your request handler finds any of these headers, it can trust that the request is a Task Queue request. If any of the above headers are present in an external user request to your app, they are stripped."

Comment: Thank you for the precision, but the part about the header is bothering me : As a client, I can add any headers to my request, including for example `X-AppEngine-QueueName`. Does GAE prevent a client to add this header ?

Comment: You could add them, but app engine will strip them: "If any of the above headers are present in an external user request to your app, they are stripped."