# how to setup a simple microservices architecture in app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I had successfully setup a single app in the app engine. 
Now I want to deploy 2-3 micro service and

read a few articles on the subject but what I really want is a simple tutorial .

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/converting

can anyone post a simple file structure as to how to do this :

- app.yaml
- micorservice1

  - folder1

    - lib1
    - lib2
  - folder2
  - htmls
  - js
  - css
  - app1.py
- micorservice2

  - folder1

    - lib1
    - lib2
  - folder2
  - htmls
  - js
  - css
  - app2.py
- index.yaml

but what is in app.yaml exactly?

how do I deploy to each microservice exactly ?

how do enable INTERNAL communication only between the microservices? I don't want external calls directly at them but via a load balancer.

Comment: Dan Cornilescu gave a decent answer to this question. "modules" are now called "services", but his answer remains in force other than a naming change. This kind of thread *is* off-topic for Stack Overflow, so you should post something like this to the [Google Groups forum for App Engine](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-appengine), where general, high-level, architecture-style advice is on-topic (notice that Stack Overflow style technical questions are on-topic *here* and off-topic there).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of year 2018 you can create multiple services within a project. These services are nothing but micro-services. Earlier GCP had the concept of modules for micro-services.

For example:

A GAE flexible application with app.yaml as

*runtime: custom

env: flex*

can be deployed using command:
*gcloud app deploy*

This command will start an application with service as **'default'**. It can be accessed through URL -> http://your-project-id.appspot.com
You can verify this on Google Cloud Console. Follow the navigator links App Engine -> Services

Similarly you can start another service in the same project with app.yaml as (additional parameter - service)

*runtime: custom 

env: flex

service: your-service-id*

It can again be deployed using the same command:
*gcloud app deploy*

This will start a new application with service id as your-service-id. The service can be accessed through url : http://your-service-id-dot-your-project-id.appspot.com or http://your-service-id.our-project-id.appspot.com

Follow the same approach to create more services in the same project. Each service is an application with it's own app.yaml

Answer (score 8):

Asking for tutorials is off-topic on SO ;)

Microservices could easily be implemented as `services` (or `modules` as they used to be called).

This Q&A *might* help in your dir structure research - [New project structure for Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35608403/new-project-structure-for-google-app-engine/35615388#35615388)

Each module has its own `.yaml` config file, the content of which depends on what the module is supposed to do. While traditionally (single-module apps) the file was named `app.yaml` that name is actually not mandatory: [Can a default service/module in a Google App Engine app be a sibling of a non-default one in terms of folder structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34110178/can-a-default-module-in-a-google-app-engine-app-be-a-sibling-of-a-non-default-mo/34111170#34111170)

Each module will run as a separate instance. Deployments in multi-module apps is done by specifying the `.yaml` file(s) of the module(s) to be deployed to the deployment utility. You have an example in my answer to post mentioned above.

Inter-module communication can easily be implemented, for example using the task queue. Which can be secured for internal-access only: [GAE task, are the urls secure by design?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36452308/gae-task-are-the-urls-secure-by-design)

See also [Microservices Architecture on Google App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/microservices-on-app-engine).